# Installing PyDev on Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

for the past few days I've been having trouble trying to install the PyDev plugin for Eclipse. I keep getting a the repository error as follows:

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=SDKProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at http://pydev.org/updates/plugins/org.python.pydev_2.5.0.2012040618.jar.
Read timed out

This has happened the last 3 or 4 days and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

this sounds like a networking problem.
I found myself failed to install BPEL plugin on eclipse.

What I do is copying the plugins from my friend's computer and put it on my eclipse plugin directory. The plugin directory location in linux is something like:

```
/home/gofrendi/.eclipse/155965261/plugins
```

while on windows, the plugin directory location is something like:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\gofrendi\My Documents\eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32\plugins
```

Just copy everything with *com.python* or *org.python* prefix

Comment: i copied them all over like you said but nothing has seemed to change, i restarted eclipse as well

Comment: maybe there are some other dependencies. How about copying the whole plugins? (please also make sure that you've make a back up before doing that)

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be a problem in the PyDev update site (just tested it here and got no other complains). So, in this situation, you can try just getting the .zip installation from sourceforge ( see url at the end of http://pydev.org/download.html ) or you can download Aptana Studio 3 ( which comes with PyDev preinstalled -- http://pydev.org/download.html also has links for that ).